# read multiple XML child nodes with the same name vb

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I'm having problems reading a list of images per node where all the images have the same node name. I'm using vb.net.
XML example below.
I can get the **propertyname** etc fine in my loop for each property but I want to put all the *img > main* nodes into a single long string to enter into a dB table.
So get all images per property.
I'll then get them out later onto an array.
Alternatively, put each image in a separate column in my dB.

Many thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scdata>
   <property>
      <propertyname><![CDATA[Legion Cottages]]></propertyname>
      <propertygroup><![CDATA[Default Group]]></propertygroup>
      <groupdisplay>individual</groupdisplay>
      <propertycode>581076</propertycode>
      <propertyurl />
      <lastupdate>29/03/2022 14:16:42</lastupdate>
      <propertytown><![CDATA[Blakeney]]></propertytown>
      <propertypostcode>NR25 7NU</propertypostcode>
      <sleeps>4</sleeps>
      <photos>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190226537.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190226537.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>1</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225352.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225352.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225355.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225355.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225356.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225356.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225357.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225357.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
      </photos>
   </property>
   <property>
      <propertyname><![CDATA[Legion Cottages]]></propertyname>
      <propertygroup><![CDATA[Default Group]]></propertygroup>
      <groupdisplay>individual</groupdisplay>
      <propertycode>581076</propertycode>
      <propertyurl />
      <lastupdate>29/03/2022 14:16:42</lastupdate>
      <propertytown><![CDATA[Blakeney]]></propertytown>
      <propertypostcode>NR25 7NU</propertypostcode>
      <sleeps>4</sleeps>
      <photos>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190226537.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190226537.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>1</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225352.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225352.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225355.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225355.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225356.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225356.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
         <img>
            <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225357.jpg" />]]></main>
            <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225357.jpg" />]]></thumb>
            <caption />
            <default>0</default>
         </img>
      </photos>
   </property>
</scdata>
```

My code

```
        Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
        doc.Load("C:\Desktop\group_46778657575556.xml")
        Dim nodes As XmlNodeList = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/scdata/property")

        Dim name, code, postcode, town, img As String


        For Each node As XmlNode In nodes

            name = node.SelectSingleNode("propertyname").InnerText
            code = node.SelectSingleNode("propertycode").InnerText
            postcode = node.SelectSingleNode("propertypostcode").InnerText
            town = node.SelectSingleNode("propertytown").InnerText
            img = ???????????????????

        Next


        For Each el As XElement In test.<property>
            sName = el.<propertyname>.Value
            sCode = el.<propertycode>.Value
            sPostcode = el.<propertypostcode>.Value
            sTown = el.<propertytown>.Value
            For Each imgND As XElement In el...<img>
                img &= imgND.<main>.Value
            Next

            sSQL = "insert into PROPERTY (" &
            "NAME, CODE, TOWN, POSTCODE,   IMG1)" &
            "values('" & sName & "','" & sCode & "','" & sTown & "', '" & sPostcode & "', '" & img & "')"

            command = New SqlCommand(sSQL, conn)
            adpter.InsertCommand = command
            adpter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this,

first the data

```
    Dim test As XElement
    ' test = XElement.Load("path here")
    'for testing use literal

    test = <scdata>
               <property>
                   <propertyname><![CDATA[Legion Cottages]]></propertyname>
                   <propertygroup><![CDATA[Default Group]]></propertygroup>
                   <groupdisplay>individual</groupdisplay>
                   <propertycode>581076</propertycode>
                   <propertyurl/>
                   <lastupdate>29/03/2022 14:16:42</lastupdate>
                   <propertytown><![CDATA[Blakeney]]></propertytown>
                   <propertypostcode>NR25 7NU</propertypostcode>
                   <sleeps>4</sleeps>
                   <photos>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190226537.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190226537.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>1</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225352.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225352.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225355.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225355.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225356.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225356.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225357.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225357.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                   </photos>
               </property>
               <property>
                   <propertyname><![CDATA[Legion Cottages]]></propertyname>
                   <propertygroup><![CDATA[Default Group]]></propertygroup>
                   <groupdisplay>individual</groupdisplay>
                   <propertycode>581076</propertycode>
                   <propertyurl/>
                   <lastupdate>29/03/2022 14:16:42</lastupdate>
                   <propertytown><![CDATA[Blakeney]]></propertytown>
                   <propertypostcode>NR25 7NU</propertypostcode>
                   <sleeps>4</sleeps>
                   <photos>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190226537.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190226537.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>1</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225352.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225352.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225355.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225355.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225356.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225356.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                       <img>
                           <main><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/190225357.jpg" />]]></main>
                           <thumb><![CDATA[<img src="https://rackcdn.com/images/cottages/thumbnails/190225357.jpg" />]]></thumb>
                           <caption/>
                           <default>0</default>
                       </img>
                   </photos>
               </property>
           </scdata>
```

and then some code

```
    Dim name, code, postcode, town, img As String

    For Each el As XElement In test.<property>
        name = el.<propertyname>.Value
        code = el.<propertycode>.Value
        postcode = el.<propertypostcode>.Value
        town = el.<propertytown>.Value
        img = "" ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        For Each imgND As XElement In el...<img>
            img &= imgND.<main>.Value
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: thanks. I'm having trouble adding the Xdocument namespace. Ive added a reference I think but still no good

Comment: To use XElement you need this namespace,  System.Xml.Linq, in the project references.

Comment: Excellent. I had trouble with the namespace because I was targeting the wrong .Net version.
Thank you!

Comment: One final thing though. The images are inserting OK but each row has the same list of images. i.e. each property is getting the same ones in the IMG1 column.

Code added to the original post

Comment: OK.  Don't know what that means.

Comment: I’d you look above at my original question I’ve put the sql insert loop code there. Each insert is giving me the same list of images for each property in the xml.

Comment: I edited the code above by adding  img = "" ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
Hope that helps.

Comment: AH ok so just reset the img var. Doh! Thanks ;)